# Is the order of the routes in the routes.rb important?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My `routes.rb` file looks like:

```
resources :contents, only: [:show]
get 'contents/by_hardware', to: 'contents#show_by_hardware'
```

With this setup I am not able to access the `contents/by_hardware` route.

But if I setup my `routes.rb` file in a different order, everthing works.

```
get 'contents/by_hardware', to: 'contents#show_by_hardware'    
resources :contents, only: [:show]
```

Is the order in the `routes.rb` file important?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that guy with 906 points at the time of asking this question didn't read documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, order matters very much.

It works like this: `resources :contents, only: [:show]` creates this route

```
content GET    /contents/:id(.:format)       contents#show
```

So when you request, for example, `http://localhost:3000/contents/by_hardware`, it is this route that matches this url. It invokes `ContentsController#show` action with params `{'id' => "by_hardware"}`. Your custom action is not considered, because matching route is already found.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, order does matter. Instead of defining routes for the same controller at two different places, I would recommend you to define routes for the above scenario this way

```
resources :contents, only: [:show] do
  get :show_by_hardware, on: :collection, path: :by_hardware
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is important, the routes will be matched from top to bottom so you can move your route `get 'contents/by_hardware', to: 'contents#show_by_hardware'` above resource to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

yes. router will match first route from the top